# Google Sheets copy between columns based on match?

Tags: google-sheets

See my following spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SO3Z-liX1T61W47gKv5ugWFiQKsHa0-XBQsi1A7dTE0/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to create a formula that I can put into column C (the missing emails) based off of the names and emails in columns E-G.

In other words, I'm only missing the emails for folks to the left. The columns on the right has the data I need. I just need a formula that will auto-fill the missing emails based on matching the names in columns A/B and E/F.

I hope that makes sense. This is just an example spreadsheet. The real sheet I need to work with has hundreds of missing emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A8&B2:B8,{E2:E14&F2:F14,G2:G14},2,0))
```