# How to do Vlookup using two search columns to compare with two result columns?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

[image]

I have google sheets with tab #1 that have the columns listed in the picture. I have tab#2 with the same info in Columns "Origin" and "Destination" but in a different order. I am trying to have the "Contract Lane Key" column show up to the corresponding rows in tab#2. In other words, I am trying to write a Vlookup that will check the "Origin" and "Destination" listed in tab#2 with the "Origin" and "Destination" columns listed in tab#1, and once both are a match, have the "Contract Lane Key" column to show up in tab#2.

Is there a way to have two search columns and match them with two result columns, to then display the Key?

This is what my vlookup looks like in tab#2:

```
=vlookup(B2:C, 'tab#1'!B2:C, 1, False)
```

This is the order of columns in both tabs:

"Contract Lane Key" is Column A

"Origin" is Column B

"Destination is Column C

Comment: You basically use the `&` operator to concatenate two columns to create a search key. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/46856944/

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are not the same. If you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. The Excel solution will not necessarily work in Google Sheets.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in 'tab#2'!A2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF((B2:B="")+(C2:C=""),,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,{'tab#1'!B2:B&'tab#1'!C2:C,'tab#1'!A2:A},2,FALSE),"no match")))`

Keep in mind that I've written this site unseen regarding your actual sheets and data. If this doesn't work, consider sharing a link to the sheet itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! You not only fixed my issue, you also taught me how to use Vlookup with multiple values in each criterion of vlookup, as I was not sure what the proper format would look like. Thanks again

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&` operator to concatenate two columns to create a new search column and a new results column.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C,{'tab#1'!B2:B&'tab#1'!C2:C,'tab#1'!A2:A},2,))
```