# Matching Columns From Different sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

There are many similar questions on here but I can not find the answer I am after.

I am working in Google Sheets and need to write a conditional formatting equation that will highlight the B:C columns if they match an entry on the second sheet in the B:C columns.  I do not know any search criteria past that which is where I keep running into an error.  All the other questions here know what they are searching for.  My work is fluid and new entries come in that may match an old one and I need to know that!

I use this formula on the first sheet to match entries specifically on the first sheet,

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($B$3:$B$389&$C$3:$C$389),$B2&$C2)>1
```

This formula works great.  If Lexington, SC is in row 2 and Lexington, SC is added again later in row 100, BAM they both light up red.  Love that.  The second equation I need is not so simple.

my data is:

SHEET 1 - Column B and Column C

| County | State |
| --- | --- |
| Lexington | SC |
| Douglas | KS |
| Chase | KS |
| Clay | OH |
| Greenwood | NY |

SHEET 2 - Column B and Column C

| County | State |
| --- | --- |
| Saratoga | NY |
| Douglas | KS |
| Chase | KS |
| Clay | OH |
| Greenwood | SC |

In this example above, I need the new formula to highlight **Douglas KS**, **Chase KS**, **Clay OH** on sheet one, because these three counties exists on Sheet Two.

I have tried MATCH, INDEX, VLOOKUP, etc.  I keep running into an issue when I want TWO columns to be compared to TWO columns.  It needs to be county name AND state.

Thank you to the community for any help you can give.  I will provide more information if it is needed!  I think this sums up my issue though.

QUERY ATTEMPTS

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($B$2:$B$20&$C$2:$C$20),$B2&$C2)>1

=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet 2'!$B$2:$B$20&$C$2:$C$20),$B2&$C2)>1

=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(indirect("Sheet1!$B$2:$B$C$2:$C"),indirect("Sheet2!$B2:$B&$C2:$C")))>1




=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:C,"Sheet 2!$B2:$C",2, FALSE),""))

=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(B2:B19, MATCH(1, FIND(E2, C2:C19)), 0))

=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(B2:C,MATCH(indirect("Sheet 2!$B2:$C"),0)))




=MATCH($B2&$C2,indirect('Sheet 2'!$B2:$B&'Sheet 2'!$C2:$C"),0)

=MATCH($B2,indirect("Sheet 2!$B2:$C"),0)

=MATCH("Sheet 1!$B2&$C2",indirect("Sheet 2!$B2:$C"),0)

=MATCH("Sheet 1!$B:$C"),indirect("Sheet 2!$B:$C"),0)

=MATCH((B2&C2),indirect("Sheet 2!(B2&C2)"),0)




=INDEX($B2:$C2,MATCH($B2&$C2,indirect("Sheet 2!$B2:$C"),0)

=INDEX(B:C,MATCH($B2&$C2,indirect("Sheet 2!$B2:$C"),0)

=INDEX(B2:C710,MATCH(0,(B:C="Sheet 2!$B:$C"),0))
```

**The only query I have gotten to work only works on the B column**

```
=match($B2,indirect("Ready to Start!$B2:$B"),0)
```

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: unable to upload an image at this time.  there is an issue in overflow.  There is a discussion about it in meta.  I am sorry for the inconvenience.  
Server Error: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  I put in the table format and it shows in the edit window properly.  When I click save, however, the table does not represent properly. It shows as seen above.  I am not sure how to fix this rendering issue.

Also any suggestion on using INDIRECT for my issue?  I'm not getting the order and arrangement correct.

Comment: Use `&` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442628/how-to-do-vlookup-using-two-search-columns-to-compare-with-two-result-columns/70442773#70442773)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestions.  I can not seem to get it right.  I was working with the ampersand before writing here but was not able to connect the dots correctly.  I edited the post to show all the variations of this query I have tried dancing around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in conditional formatting (and data validation) whenever you want to refer to another sheet, that sheet's range needs to be `INDIRECT`ed. if you got a joint range (like you do) both of them need to be wrapped in `INDIRECT`

try:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($B$3:$B$389&$C$3:$C$389),
 INDIRECT("Sheet 2!B2")&INDIRECT("Sheet 2!C2"))>1
```

or:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Sheet 2!B3:B389")&INDIRECT("Sheet 2!C3:C389")),
 $B2&$C2)>1
```

but note that this will work only if let's say B4&C4 on BOTH sheets are the same.

if one sheet compared to other has different sorting of the same values you will need a completely different formula...

if your sheets are named exactly:

```
Sheet 1
Sheet 2
```

try this in Sheet 1:

```
=($A2<>"")*REGEXMATCH($A2&$B2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 INDIRECT("Sheet 2!A2:A")&INDIRECT("Sheet 2!B2:B")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I have seen the INDIRECT command when searching this.  I did get that to work when looking at only the B column.  I could not get INDIRECT to work when trying to do B&C together.  Do you mean like this?


=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(indirect("Sheet1!$B$3:$B$389&$C$3:$C$389"),indirect("Sheet2!$B2:$B&$C2:$C")))>1


could you attempt an example from what I wrote?  I can make it work from there, I think.

Comment: Here is the formula that successfully checks the B column from sheet 1 and sheet 2

=match($B2,indirect("Ready to Start!$B2:$B"),0)

Any attempt I make to have this match work with the B AND C columns, fails.  any advice would be very helpful!

Comment: @KJP for `B&C` it would be: `INDIRECT("B2:B")&INDIRECT("C2:C")`

Comment: @KJP answer updated

Comment: Wow thanks @player0!  I will give this a look over today and see if I can incorporate it.  Unfortunately the sheets are NOT the same values in the same order.  It is ever changing with different county and state combinations.  I need these to highlight on sheet 1 if they are on sheet 2.  You mention I will need a different formula for that.  Please share any suggestions you have!

Comment: @KJP answer updated

Comment: thank you for following up and adding those points!  I am still running into a wall, though.  First, sometimes my manager likes to name the sheets.  How would the formula differ if we were using 'County Pool' and 'Ready'?  Secondly, I also mocked up a fresh sheet to recreate your example and could not get the query shared above to work.  Your example is exactly what I want!  Any advice would be incredible!  Thank you for your time with this.

Comment: @KJP here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W7H9wlqgANE-QtAfhi8kOTGYHAkloOqrLUcw11C18Qs/edit#gid=1522903271

Comment: thank you for sharing the spreadsheet.  I was able to find the issue.  The query you shared highlights Sheet 1 if Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are the same.  This is not the case in my work.  I am sorry for not making that clear.  Hancock, WV may be record 5 on Sheet 1 and record 120 on Sheet 2.  We have a revolving county system and any county could come in and be any record.  This is why I need to know if what we enter on Sheet 1 already exists on Sheet 2, anywhere on the sheet.  Thank you for your continued help!  You have already shown me a ton here.  Very instructive.